# Why "ancien français" and not "français ancien?"

Tags: adjectifs

I'm wondering why Old French is translated as "ancien français" and not "français ancien?" I thought that "ancien" before a noun translated to "former," while "ancien" after a noun translated to "ancient." Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Former*** is certainly part of the meaning here. When preceding the noun it qualifies, ***ancien*** often means no longer in use, that existed before the current like ***ancien régime*** for *monarchie*, ***ancien franc*** (before the *nouveau franc*), ***Ancien Testament*** (Old Testament).

This usage might have also been influenced by the form ***vieux français***.